# Should HELO, MAILFROM and From use the same domain?

Tags: email, email-server, spf, dkim, dmarc

I configured a mail server a couple of times before and I believe back then I thought
that the answer is "yes."

But I'm about to configure another one, and it seems that I was wrong. Let's say the apex domain (`example.com`) and the (only) MX record point to the same server (`mail.example.com`). Then I can make:

- `example.com` point to the server IP (`aa.aaa.aa.aaa`) and point it back (PTR) to `example.com`
- a mail server (`postfix`, `exim`, ...) respond with `example.com` (`HELO`, `MAILFROM`)

Then the SPF, DKIM and DMARC record names are: `@`, `mail._domainkey` (if selector is `mail`) and `_dmarc`. Or to put it briefly:

```
@  A  aa.aaa.aa.aaa
@  MX  10  mail
mail  A  aa.aaa.aa.aaa
aa.aaa.aa.aaa  PTR  @

@  TXT  (SPF)
mail._domainkey  TXT  (DKIM)
_dmarc  TXT  (DMARC)
```

But what if I have 2 MX records (`mail1` and `mail2`)? Then I can't make `example.com` point to 2 different IPs and point them back to `example.com`, can I? But even if I can, I can see that Gmail doesn't use `gmail.com` for `HELO`, `MAILFROM`. And it seems more sensible for each server to respond with its own name, doesn't it? But then what, I should have 2 SPF records? After all:

> the current version of SPF — called SPFv1 or SPF Classic — protects the envelope sender address

http://www.open-spf.org/Introduction/

```
@  A  (whatever)

@  MX  10  mail1
mail1  A  aa.aaa.aa.aaa
aa.aaa.aa.aaa  PTR  mail1

@  MX  20  mail2
mail2  A  bb.bbb.bb.bbb
bb.bbb.bb.bbb  PTR  mail2

mail1  TXT  (SPF)
mail2  TXT  (SPF)
mail._domainkey  TXT  (DKIM)
_dmarc  TXT  (DMARC)
```

To be frank I'm confused after reading different articles and answers on configuring a mail server. What is the correct or a better setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The HELO hostname can be different from the sender

The `HELO` hostname should have a matching `A` & `PTR`, but they do not have to match the domain used in neither [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) `MAIL FROM` nor [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2) *originator fields* `From` header – nor even share an *organizational domain*.

E.g., `mail1.example.com` & `mail2.example.com` could well send mail for `example.com`, `example.net` & `example.org`. Otherwise, every domain would need an own IP address with a matching `PTR` record. Think of the amount off domains large email service providers are handling, and they certainly use a common infrastructure for them all.

### MX records are for incoming mail

The `MX` records do not relate to sending mail but to receiving it. In the scope of your question there is not any kind of relation between them. The inbound mail could be handled by a different set of servers altogether. E.g., newsletters from a domain could be sent using SendGrid or MailChimp while the incoming mail is handled by M365 or Gmail.

### Origin of HELO/DNS mismatches

Using `HELO` / `A` / `PTR` mismatches as an indication of spam is common, as described by, e.g., MXToolBox:

- [SMTP Banner Check](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-banner-check):

  > Some receiving mail servers may use a mismatched or masked banner as an indication of a possible spam source in a scoring system, but most will not reject incoming mail solely on this basis.
- [SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch):

  > Some receiving mail servers may use this as an indication of a possible spam source in a scoring system.  Most will not reject incoming mail solely on this basis.  We recommend that you contact your ISP and ask them to setup a reverse record (PTR) that matches the hostname of your mail server.

This practice probably comes from an interpretation of [RFC 5321, 2.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.5):

> The domain name given in the `EHLO` command MUST be either a primary
> host name (a domain name that resolves to an address RR) or, if
> the host has no name, an address literal, as described in
> [Section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.3) and discussed further in the `EHLO` discussion of
> [Section 4.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.4).

However, it is not a hard requirement, as the [4.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.4) further defines, that:

> The SMTP client MUST, if possible, ensure that the domain parameter
> to the `EHLO` command is a primary host name as specified for this
> command in [Section 2.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.5).  If this is not possible (e.g., when the
> client's address is dynamically assigned and the client does not have
> an obvious name), an address literal SHOULD be substituted for the
> domain name.
>
> An SMTP server MAY verify that the domain name argument in the `EHLO`
> command actually corresponds to the IP address of the client.
> However, if the verification fails, the server MUST NOT refuse to
> accept a message on that basis.

Here, the SMTP protocol seems to follow the *robustness principle* i.e. "be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others".

### SPF

It is mandatory for the *Sender Policy Framework* (SPF) implementations to protect the `MAIL FROM` identity ([RFC 7208, 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-2.4)) and it can optionally protect the `HELO` identity ([RFC 7208, 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-2.3)), too:

> It is RECOMMENDED that SPF verifiers not only check the `MAIL FROM`
> identity but also separately check the `HELO` identity by applying
> the `check_host()` function ([Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4)) to the `HELO` identity as the
> `<sender>`.  Checking `HELO` promotes consistency of results and can
> reduce DNS resource usage.  If a conclusive determination about the
> message can be made based on a check of `HELO`, then the use of DNS
> resources to process the typically more complex `MAIL FROM` can be
> avoided.

As this is done independently, SPF does not require them to match, either.

SPF protects the hostname from being used as the *envelope sender* without permission, and it is not inherited by the subdomains. Therefore, you should protect every `A` record you have with a corresponding `TXT` SPF record – not just the ones you are using for sending email.

### DMARC

The *Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting, and Conformance* (DMARC) requires a match between [RFC5322.From](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2) and the Identifier Alignment as defined in [RFC 7439, 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html#section-3.1). Those identifiers can either be DKIM-Authenticated [(3.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html#section-3.1.1)) or SPF-Authenticated ([3.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html#section-3.1.2)) and depending on the mode it could require an exact match or a shared *organizational domain* ([3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html#section-3.2)). Unlike SPF, DMARC is inherited; a DMARC policy at the domain apex protects all the subdomains from being used in the `From` header, too.

The SPF alignment requires a matching `MAIL FROM`, but the DKIM alignment does not; it is sufficient to have a valid and authorized DKIM signature with a matching *signing Domain identifier* (SDID) (`d=` field). As a bottom line, neither of these requires a matching `HELO`/`EHLO` hostname.

Comment: RMX is deprecated - and superceded by SPF - so having a valid PTR record *should* be redundant. But there are still some people out there checking these records.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. `you should protect every A record you have with a corresponding TXT SPF record` Every A record that points to a mail server, or literally every A record? `a match between RFC5322.From and the Identifier Alignment` I believe Identifier Alignment is a match between RFC5322.From and an Authenticated Identifier. `it is sufficient to have a valid and authorized DKIM signature with a matching SDID`Is it stated so in RFCs?

Comment: I guess I've found [the place](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html#section-6.6.2): `If one or more of the Authenticated Identifiers align with the RFC5322.From domain, the message is considered to pass the DMARC mechanism check.` But I guess having DKIM and SPF alignment is better than having only one of them.

Comment: Literally every `A` record. Otherwise, anyone can use `sub.example.com` as the envelope sender.

Comment: It is recommended to have at least DMARC+DKIM alignment, as it survives forwarding, e.g., when a mailing list legitimately rewrites the envelope sender to pass SPF, but loses the DMARC+SPF alignment. The DMARC specification says it passes with either, but some may use them independently for spam scoring – just like the HELO mismatches here that aren't really against the SMTP protocol. However, DMARC is not an anti-spam technology, but anti-spoofing. Spammers can well set up all SPF, DKIM & DMARC for their own domain, and they do.